# Insert a line at the end of an ini section only if it doesn't exist

Tags: awk, sed, sh, ini, samba

I have an `smb.conf` ini file which is overwritten whenever edited with a certain GUI tool, wiping out a custom setting. This means I need a cron job to ensure that one particular section in the file contains a certain `option=value` pair, and insert it at the end of the section if it doesn't exist.

**Example**

Ensure that `hosts deny=192.168.23.` exists within the `[myshare]` section:

```
  [global]
    printcap name = cups
    winbind enum groups = yes
    security = user
[myshare]
    path=/mnt/myshare
    browseable=yes
    enable recycle bin=no
    writeable=yes
    hosts deny=192.168.23.
 [Another Share]
    invalid users=nobody,nobody
    valid users=nobody,nobody
    path=/mnt/share2
    browseable=no
```

**Long-winded solution using awk**

After a long time struggling with sed, I concluded that it might not be the right tool for the job. So I moved over to awk and came up with this:

```
#!/bin/sh
file="smb.conf"
tmp="smb.conf.tmp"
section="myshare"
opt="hosts deny=192.168.23."

awk '
    BEGIN {
        this_section=0;
        opt_found=0;
    }
    # Match the line where our section begins
    /^[ \t]*\['"$section"'\][ \t]*$/ {
        this_section=1;
        print $0;
        next;
    }
    # Match lines containing our option
    this_section == 1 && /^[ \t]*'"$opt"'[ \t]*$/ {
        opt_found=1;
    }
    # Match the following section heading
    this_section == 1 && /^[ \t]*\[.*$/ {
        this_section=0;
        if (opt_found != 1) {
            print "\t'"$opt"'";
        }
    }
    # Print every line
    { print $0; }
    END {
        # In case our section is the very last in the file
        if (this_section == 1 && opt_found != 1) {
            print "\t'"$opt"'";
        }
    }
' $file > $tmp

# Overwrite $file only if $tmp is different
diff -q $file $tmp > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    mv $tmp $file
    # reload smb.conf here
else
    rm $tmp
fi
```

I can't help feeling that this is a long script  to achieve a simple task. Is there a more efficient/elegant way to insert a property in an ini file using basic shell tools like sed and awk?

Comment: I disagree with the statement "This means I need a cron job".  What this really means is that you either need to figure out how to configure the gui so that it doesn't wipeout your setting, or you need to stop using the gui.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Python 3's `configparser`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
from configparser import SafeConfigParser

cfg = SafeConfigParser()
cfg.read(sys.argv[1])

cfg['myshare']['hosts deny'] = '192.168.23.';

with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as f:
    cfg.write(f)
```

To be called as `./filename.py smb.conf` (i.e., the first parameter is the file to change).

Note that comments are not preserved by this. However, since a GUI overwrites the config and doesn't preserve custom options, I suspect that comments are already nuked and that this is not a worry in your case.

Comment: Very tidy. Nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, should work though

```
awk -vT="hosts deny=192.168.23" 'x&&$0~T{x=0}x&&/^ *\[[^]]+\]/{print "\t\t"T;x=0}
                                /^ *\[myshare\]/{x++}1' file
```

Comment: If you explain your code more people would probably be more likely to vote for it, I had to adjust the spacing but this works.

Comment: @A.Danischewski I thought it was pretty basic and didn't need one, also what spacing did you have to adjust ?

Comment: `@JID` it is sometimes difficult to think that someone cant read the manual pages and see the logic, but a lot of people use this website to help learn by example and a little bit of explanation of some of the concepts is very much appreciated by them. On my system I had to replace `\t\t` with four spaces to make it align with the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit awkward. It uses the INI section header as the record separator. This means that there is an empty record *before* the first header, so when we match the header we're interested in, we have to read the *next* record to handle that INI section. Also, there are some `printf` commands because the records still contain leading and trailing newlines.

```
awk -v RS='[[][^]]+[]]' -v str="hosts deny=192.168.23." '
    {printf "%s", $0; printf "%s", RT} 
    RT == "[myshare]" {
        getline
        printf "%s", $0
        if (index($0, str) == 0) print str
        printf "%s", RT
    }
' smb.conf
```

`RS` is the awk variable that contains the regex to split the text into records.
`RT` is the awk variable that contains the actual text of the current record separator.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for a couple of extensions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
index($0,str) { found = 1 }
match($0,/^\s*\[([^]]+).*/,a) {
    if ( (name == tgt) && !found ) { print indent str }
    name = a[1]
    found = 0
}
{ print; indent=gensub(/\S.*/,"","") }
```

.

```
$ awk -v tgt="myshare" -v str="hosts deny=192.168.23." -f tst.awk file
[global]
    printcap name = cups
    winbind enum groups = yes
    security = user
[myshare]
    path=/mnt/myshare
    browseable=yes
    enable recycle bin=no
    writeable=yes
    hosts deny=192.168.23.
[Another Share]
    invalid users=nobody,nobody
    valid users=nobody,nobody
    path=/mnt/share2
    browseable=no
```

.

```
$ awk -v tgt="myshare" -v str="fluffy bunny" -f tst.awk file
[global]
    printcap name = cups
    winbind enum groups = yes
    security = user
[myshare]
    path=/mnt/myshare
    browseable=yes
    enable recycle bin=no
    writeable=yes
    hosts deny=192.168.23.
    fluffy bunny
[Another Share]
    invalid users=nobody,nobody
    valid users=nobody,nobody
    path=/mnt/share2
    browseable=no
```